# Cisco UCCE Password Change via SQL

Tags: c#, sql, voip, cisco

We are developing an application to change the password for users in our UCCE environment. I have found where this data is stored and I can update the password for a user.

However it seems to only work on the web based applications in out UCCE environment and not the physical applications like CAD and CSD. For the life of me I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Has anyone ever done this successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the response I got from Cisco

Hi all,
First, you could have some LDAP issues, but sync does go out and check for changes every 10 minutes.  You could have an LDAP sync issue.   Second, the supervisor password is not stored in the same table.  The table I mentioned is for agents.  The supervisor password is stored in a couple different places including updating the AD, and I don’t believe it’s as easy to change as the agent table.  Also, the password is not updated at the desktop – it is only stored in LDAP and validated when an agent tries to log in

Also, just by changing it in SQL, I’m not sure that that’s all to having it populated across to the other logger, HDS, etc (in fact I’m pretty sure it won’t).  The normal way would be to make a change in the AW which would then push that change to the router (via UPCC.dll) which sends the change to the loggers to update their database, and finally back to the AW as a confirmation as well as the other AW/HDS’s.  There’s certain checks/procedures for changes to be populated – one being the recover key on each server.

By what you are trying to do, you most likely will be causing corruption across all the databases because they are dependent on the recovery key to ensure they are all in sync.  So I’m not so sure that changing it in SQL is a very good idea, nor would it be supported by Cisco or Calabrio.  You most likely will be corrupting the database since you are bypassing the way the Central Controller keeps everything synchronized.

Lastly, CAD wouldn’t have anything to do with this/these changes – it would only query the database and update LDAP, but as mentioned I think you are changing the agent password and therefore the supervisor is not being changed.  I would seriously urge you not to try and change anything in SQL as we seen enough cases where the databases get out of sync and/or corrupted – not a lot of fun when that happens!

Hope that helps explain a bit more.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score -1):

Correct 
The Password change which you doing in SQL wont populated across to the other AW / HDS , ETC.
I’m 100% sure it won’t and you will face

1. The Recovery Key Mismatch Issue.
2. _Real_Time Table Data Mismatched Issue means synchronization Issue.